# Tapestry 5.3 Appending html at the end of body via Custom Component

Tags: java, tapestry

I have seen many tutorials on adding html programmatically via MarkupWriter, but it adds the html where the component is used.

Is there any way to tell the writer to add it just before the closing body tag ?

Also, how can I get the body of the component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it needs to be that complex

```
@Environmental
private Heartbeat heartbeat;

@SetupRender
void setupRender(MarkupWriter writer) {
    writer.element("div");
}

// let the body render as normal

@AfterRender
void afterRender(final MarkupWriter writer) {
    Element wrapper = writer.element();
    writer.end();
    final String bodyMarkup = wrapper.getChildMarkup();

    // remove the body 
    wrapper.remove();

    heartbeat.defer(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Element pageBody = writer.getDocument().find("html/body");
            pageBody.raw(bodyMarkup);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I was mislead by the tapestry wiki page on obtaining the body

Comment: I think the wiki page you were referring to was looping over the body multiple times with different property values being rendered each time. Your use-case is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

To get the body of a component, you should @Inject ComponentResources and call getBody().

To add something to the end of the body requires slightly more thought. I can see two ways.

Using the @HeartbeatDeferred annotation, you can access the DOM after all other components have rendered. Something like this:

```
public class MyComponent {
    private Element body;

    void setupRender(MarkupWriter writer) {
        body = writer.getDocument().find("html/body");
    }

    @HeartbeatDeferred
    void addToBody() {
        body.text("Some text here");
    }
}
```

Another way is to define a component directly under the body tag which nests all other components. This component pushes a model object onto the environment in it's @SetupRender method. Components defined as children to the top level component could then use the @Environmental annotation to lookup the model object and contribute to it. The top level component then renders the model.

eg:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <t:toplevelcomponent>
          <t:childcomponent />
          <div>...</div>
          <div>...</div>
       </t:toplevelcomponent>
   </body>
</html>

public class TopLevelModel {
    private List<String> contributions;

    // getters and setters
}

public class TopLevelComponent {
      @Inject
      Environment environment;

      public void setupRender() {
          environment.push(TopLevelModel.class, new TopLevelModel());
      }

      public void afterRender(MarkupWriter writer) {
          TopLevelModel model = environment.pop(TopLevelModel.class);
          for (String contribution : model.getContributions()) {
              // add text to the body tag
              writer.getElement().text(contribution); 
          }
      }
}

public class ChildComponent {
      @Environmental
      private TopLevelModel topLevelModel;

      public void setupRender() {
           topLevelModel.getContributions().add("Foo");
           topLevelModel.getContributions().add("Bar");
      }
}
```

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but I am trying to keep things as simple as possible, so I'll just use the first sample

Comment: Appending to the body didn't work with the annotation (the reason unknown), but the following did work
`@Environmental
    private Heartbeat heartbeat;

    @SetupRender
    private void setupRender(MarkupWriter writer) {
        pageBody = writer.getDocument().find("html/body");
        
        Runnable appendToBody = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pageBody.text("find-me-now");
            }
        };
        heartbeat.defer(appendToBody);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

The Solution:

```
    private Element pageBody;
    private String componentBodyMarkup;
    private Element wrapper;

    @Environmental
    private Heartbeat heartbeat;

    @SetupRender
    private RenderCommand setupRender() {
        return new RenderCommand() {
            public void render(MarkupWriter writer, RenderQueue queue) {
                wrapper = writer.element("div");

                RenderCommand renderBody = new RenderCommand() {
                    public void render(MarkupWriter writer, RenderQueue queue2) {
                        RenderCommand bodyRenderCommand = typeCoercer.coerce(componentResources.getBody(), RenderCommand.class);
                        queue2.push(bodyRenderCommand);
                    }
                };
                queue.push(renderBody);
            }
        };
    }

    @BeforeRenderBody
    private boolean beforeRenderBody(MarkupWriter writer) {
        return false;
    }

    @AfterRender
    private void afterRender(MarkupWriter writer) {
        pageBody = writer.getDocument().find("html/body");

        writer.end();

        componentBodyMarkup = wrapper.getChildMarkup();
        wrapper.remove();

        Runnable appendToBody = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pageBody.raw(componentBodyMarkup);
            }
        };
        heartbeat.defer(appendToBody);
    }
```